# Add a title to a table created with reactable

Tags: r

I created a table with the package reactable but i'am not sure how to add a title to it.
I have a few examples in Github where they add one, but i can't reach the same results.
This is my code:

```
library(reactable)
library(htmltools)
example<- reactable(data.frame(country=c("argentina","brazil"),
                     value=c(1,2)
                     ))
div(class = "table",
    div(class = "title", "Top CRAN Packages of 2019"),
    example
)
print(example)
```

This is an example where they add a title to a table among other things that i used to try to add my title:

https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/twitter-followers/twitter-followers.html

Answer (score 4):

The `reactable` function returns a special object that happens to use the `htmlwidgets` package to help with rendering. You can use the `htmlwidgets::prependContent` function to add HTML content to the object for your header. For example

```
withtitle <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(example, 
    h2(class = "title", "Top CRAN Packages of 2019"))

print(withtitle)
```

This places the `<h2>` header tag and content before the table element when it prints.

Comment: Thank you! You are amazing!

Comment: For anyone looking to apply this solution in a Shiny app, just a heads up that this function is documented that it will not work in a Shiny rendering function (https://rdrr.io/cran/htmlwidgets/man/prependContent.html)